# Query on mysqldump

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use mysqldump for backing up my database and restoring the same in remote a machine for disaster recovery purposes. As I havent used it before, I am having a basic question regarding the same.

Once I dumped and copied over the file,on the target machine, while importing, will it perform the import such a way that it creates new entities while updating any existing ones and deleting any entities deleted in the dump?

Basically, will it keep the target mysql in sync with the dump i.e. the same as on the source?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look to the file produced by `mysqldump`. It contains SQL statements. Basically it creates each table and populates it using `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short(ish):
Mysqldump will create an SQL file that, when imported in an empty environment, makes a database that is the same as the one the dump was created from.

**So no:** it will not "sync" anything (e.g. delete files or update records). You can actually look at the file and you will see statements that first create a database, then create the tables and finally insert your data.

They way it works that you take an empty server, import the database and you have you origional situation back. Nothing less, but definitely nothing more as well.

Comment: Thanks @Nanne If this is mainly towards the first-time dump, wondering what is the alternate mechasnim to keep the databases in sync from time to time. I was thinking to use this mechanism scheduled on a daily basis to keep the megastores in sync at the end of the day.

Comment: I'm not really sure what kind of setup you have, and there are many, many possiblities that are not suited for a discussion here. You could look in to master-slave replication, incremental backups (e.g. innobackupex by percona), or just load that dump every night even. All of them are valid possibilities

Comment: Thanks @Nanne probably, a daily dump and import would serve our purpose. When checking the dump output, it has a drop query in the top, then create and finally insert. So its kind of fresh-import everyday. That would serve our purposes at the moment. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @greenhorntechie use the `--add-drop-database` option to include a `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ...` statement into the dump file immediately before the `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE` statements.  Also... helpful tip (n00bs tend to have their minds blown by this): be aware that things like `/*!50001 ... */` that you'll see in the dump file are **not** comments.  They are statements that execute normally when loading the dump file, as long as the target server is the listed version or higher (e.g. 50001 = 5.00.01 = 5.0.1).  Old servers ignore them.  This is a backwards compatibility feature.